# Convert addresses on separate lines into one row each

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that has several rows but I need to convert them to columns. So each row is actually one column. I have this

```
Name
Address
City
Info
Website
"Empty Space"


Name
Address
City
Info
Website
"Empty Space"
```

but I want:

```
Name   Address   City   Info   Website
Name   Address   City   Info   Website
Name   Address   City   Info   Website
```

My document has 22,467 rows and I also don't know how to create and run a macro for this. I really appreciate your help. I have already tried transpose but it gives me error. I am using Microsoft Office 2008 on Mac.

Comment: is the **Empty Space** a constant amount of space, or can it vary?

Comment: If you do indeed have Excel 2008 for Mac, you won't be able to create a macro, as macros are not supported in that version. As for the transpose, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each block is 5 rows of Name/Address/City/Info/Website and each block is separated by three blank rows and the first `Name` is in A1, then in B1, copied across to F1:

```
=OFFSET($A1,MOD(ROW(),9)/9+COLUMN()-2,0)
```

In G1:

```
=MOD(ROW(),9)
```

Copy B1:G1 down to suit. Then select and copy entire sheet and Paste Special, Values over the top.

Filter ColumnG to select all but `0` and delete all visible rows and delete ColumnA.